# Uso di "per intanto" versus "intanto"

Tags: word-usage, prepositions

Quantomeno nella lingua parlata gradisco sentire "per intanto", per esempio,  "per intanto risolviamo questi problemi, in seguito decideremo più precisamente cosa fare".

È corretto? O, invece,  sarebbe corretto dire "intanto risolviamo ... cosa fare", senza "per" all'inizio?

Comment: http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/intanto/

Comment: Apparently it is correct, although in my opinion quite old-fashioned (*old-fashioned as in 17th century*). Note that "intanto" is more common, and sufficient. Alternatively "nel frattempo" would also sound ok.

Comment: "Per adesso"/"tanto per cominciare"/"prima di tutto" all seem more natural in the example you've made.

Answer (score 3):

Tecnicamente fa parte della lingua italiana: vedi [il Vocabolario Treccani](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/intanto/) per esempio, che dice alla voce "intanto" *«Preceduto da per (o anche senza) equivale a «per ora, per il momento»: questo per i. può bastare; i. paga tu, poi ci divideremo la spesa. »*

All'atto pratico, credo che l'uso sia sentito come non-italiano.

Comment: A me suona naturalissimo (se un po' affettato). Sono anzi sorpreso da questo rigetto di un'espressione normalissima della lingua italiana

Answer (score 2):

Per chi lo considera “old-fashioned as in 17th century”: se lo è, lo è più “as in [first half of 20th century](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=per%20intanto&year_start=1500&year_end=2000&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1;,per%20intanto;,c0)”: per qualche motivo pare aver goduto di una notorietà che ha culminato verso il 1950. (Ciò detto, a me non piace molto, ma io non sono nessuno.)

Comment: Note that the tool should be handled with care, otherwise beginners would consider acceptable the use of "[per l'intanto](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=per+l+'+intanto&case_insensitive=on&year_start=1500&year_end=2000&corpus=22&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t4%3B%2Cper%20l%20%27%20intanto%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bper%20l%20%27%20intanto%3B%2Cc0%3B%3BPer%20l%20%27%20intanto%3B%2Cc0)" as well (recent peak in 1989!) - I hope you agree it does not sound like good Italian. (It seems the link is not working - you can obtain the plot by inserting the text "per l'intanto")

Comment: DaG, ma non dovrebbe dirsi 'che *è* culminata', piuttosto che 'che ha culminato'?

Comment: @randomatlabuser: Of course statistical considerations like those to be gleaned from Google Ngrams have no prescriptive value. We had already ascertained from Treccani Dictionary that “per intanto” is not incorrect, and I just added some data about its use in time.

Comment: Well spotted, @KyriakosKyritsis!

Comment: @randomatlabuser: I am noticing now that, by having Ngrams show simultaneously “per intanto” and “per l'intanto”, the former is the more frequent by at least one order of magnitude.

Comment: And "per ora" or "nel frattempo" are more frequent than "per intanto" by at least another order :-) Note that "per intanto" appears in the 4° edition (1729-1738) of the ["Vocabolario degli accademici della Crusca"](http://www.lessicografia.it/INTANTOCHE)